# I am looking for a story about a creator god with tribal-sounding name

Tags: story-identification

I never read this book. It might not be a book. It might be a poem. But I remember reading a summary of it a long time ago. The book is about a creator god. The creator god has (what to my Western sensibilities sounds like) a tribal name. The god creates an avatar with an equally tribal sounding name. The avatar creates the world and rebels against his creator by creating his own world. I am aware this is not much to go on. Does it sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: What do you mean by "tribal?"  There are many groups of people, in all regions of the world, speaking a huge number of different languages, that could be or have been described as "tribes."  So what is a "tribal-sounding name?"  [Shkreli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shkreli_(tribe))?  [Mundiya Kepanga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mundiya_Kepanga)?

Comment: @DavidW It was some sort of name that to me evoked the idea that these are the sort of names people had shortly after they descended from the trees in central Africa and started giving names to things. I wish I could be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's a long-shot, but could this be *[The Circular Ruins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Circular_Ruins)* by [Jorge Luis Borges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jorge_Luis_Borges). I don't recall any rebellion, but there are some similarities in the creation aspect. The Zend tribe (now known as [Zand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zand_(tribe))) are mentioned.

In this story, a man comes down a river searching for a place to worship. He finds a circular ruin of a temple and falls asleep. Once asleep, in his dream he starts teaching a large class of students in all aspects of knowledge, narrowing down candidates for a soul to participate in the universe. After various dreams, he develops insomnia and has to start again. This time he then dreams of creating a man piece by piece, starting with the heart. This dream man is to be his son and sent out into the world, but the dreamer can not make him real, so  prays to the gods of the ruin he is in. The god named "Fire" promises that he will make the son real and that the dreamer must send his son out into the world to spread word of the god "Fire" and that the son will not be harmed by fire, because the fire will know that he is not a real person.

The dreamer sends his son out in to the world and eventually receives word of a man (his son) down-river, who can walk on water. The dreamer's temple is then overcome by a forest fire, which he walks into, but is not burned. This leads him to the realization that he too is a dream.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't really fit the name portion, but the plot description is a dead match for the second universe plotline of [the 2000 DC Lucifer series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer_(DC_Comics)#Solo_series).

In DC's history, after Jehovah created the universe, Lucifer personally crafted the stars and planets. During the series, Lucifer creates a second universe and IIRC his only demand of the residents is that they do not worship a higher power. He offers to let people choose to leave Jehovah's universe and come live in his instead.